# Inline css attched to component Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am facing a weird issue with angular 4, that what happened on local everything is working fine but after deployment to development server a dynamic css is going to attached with the component.

```
<app-language-results _ngcontent-c2 style="display: none;" _nghost-c4 class="ng-tns-c4-8 ng-tns-c2-1" ng-reflect-search-results="[object Object],[object Object">…</app-language-results>
---- Some CODE----
</app-language-results>
```

So guys, If can give some suggestion it will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's Fixed. That was because of NPM issue. On my development server, There was NPM 5.4 version & on my local NPM 5.3 version.